# PHP preg_split IPs in a string

Tags: php, arrays, ip, preg-split

I am trying to use `preg_split` in PHP to break up the following string and return me the 2 ip addresses:

```
$membersStr = "members { 167.69.27.151:4449 {} 167.69.27.153:4449 {} 167.69.27.154:4449 { session user disabled } 167.67.27.156:4449 }";
```

My code is:

```
$nodesArray = preg_split("/\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/", $membersStr, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

then simply print it for now:

```
print_r($nodesArray);
```

However it is an empty array. I double checked my regular expression from an online checker and it returns the IP.

Trying :

```
preg_match_all('/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/', $membersStr, $nodesArray);
echo $nodesArray[0];
```

Prints:

```
Array
```

In my browser.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that complex of a Regex here. Use this Regex to pluck out the IPs inside the first set of brackets:

```
members \{(.*)\}
```

Take the first group (what is between the parentheses). Then `explode()` on `{}` to get each IP. Iterate over each value, trim it, and make sure it isn't blank.

**Edit**

Try this:

```
$membersStr = "members { 167.69.27.151:4449 {} 167.69.27.153:4449 {} }";

$ips = explode("{", $membersStr, 2);
$ips = explode("{}", $ips[1]);

foreach ($ips as $ip){
    $ip = trim($ip);
    if ($ip != "" && $ip != "}")
        echo $ip . "<br/>";
}
```

### SAMPLE PULLED FROM FILE

```
 members {
      167.69.97.48:4440 {
         session user disabled
      }
      167.69.97.91:4440 {}
   }
```

**Edit**

Use the other answer, but like this:

```
$membersStr = @" members {
      167.69.97.48:4440 {
         session user disabled
      }
      167.69.97.91:4440 {}
   }";

preg_match_all('/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/', $membersStr, $nodesArray);

foreach ($nodesArray[0] as $ip)
    echo $ip . "<br/>";
```

Comment: Let me work up some example code for you, and then you can try it

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: My membersStr is grabbed from a file with newlines in it..do you think this would cause that error?

Comment: It might. Can you post an exact copy of a sample membersStr, including new lines?

Comment: It's complaining about this line $ips = explode("{}", $ips[1]);

Comment: I am using file_get_contents to populate $membersStr . Is that the issue?

Comment: It won't matter how you are getting the data. What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you use your existing regular expression for splitting, then the matched part will certainly not part of the result list. Instead you'll get the empty space and fill stuff in between.

Therefore it's simpler if you match and extract the parts that you actually want:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/', $str, $matches);
$list = $matches[0];
```